# How to achieve Oculus UI in .Net WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to achieve this look&feel in WPF.
It basically acts like a TabControl, with the tabs on the left (vertically)
The right side of the window completely changes depending on which item you have clicked on the left "nav bar":

[Oculus UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4uD3.png)

What I did:
I started doing a Custom Control. A grid with two columns, a StackPanel in the left column in which there will be a clickable button/label for every menu entry (vertically of course). A Property MenuEntries which is a `List<string>`.

1. How do I get the control to add a "tabpage" (a grid/canvas?) programmatically for every MenuEntry the user adds at design time?
2. How can I achieve the behavior of the TabControl during design time, i.e. the content on the right side changes as soon as the user clicks an item on the left (in the designer/editor)? (kind of like the TabControl itself?)
3. Is this the right approach or would you do that completely differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use TabControl for that, just set `TabStripPlacement="Left"`, (some more [details](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/tabcontrol/tab-positions/))

The whole rest: colors, margins etc is set via styles.

Also, to save you a lot of trouble, use MVVM (with some framework for WPF) for that. Set ViewModel collection as ItemsSource for the TabControl.

Then, when you select one of the tabs, the control will display the view for the selected VM.

**DO NOT set TabItems in xaml for each tab, this is wrong way to go in the long run.**

Comment: hey thanks a lot!!!! I don't quite understand this sentence "Set ViewModel collection as ItemsSource for the TabControl." Which ViewModel collection? I thought this is only used for databinding? Any reference for that?

Comment: yes, this is DataBinding. [Here](http://putridparrot.com/blog/binding-to-the-tabcontrols-itemssource-and-more/) you can find a good overview. You can also take a look at ReactiveUI and it's view locationg system, very usefull